# How to use android:layout_weight with listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to set UI based on `android:layout_weight`.I have following code structure

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/relatedContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    here=""
    problem=""
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector_color" >
</ListView>
```

Everything work properly but when we set ListView id then it streatch all layout.So please can anyone help me out about this.Thanks

Comment: if you're setting listview's android:layout_weight="50" then you should set its height to "0px" so it'll set it %50 of parent view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="25"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/relatedContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: same issue sir, I don't know why this problem occur,Logically this should not occur,

Comment: wat does actually stretch? listview or button containers?

Comment: stretch mean layout fit automatically no effect of android:layout_weight.

Comment: it works just fine, if u paste the above code. I have tried by removin tag. Also please tell how are u accessing view withoud providing id

Comment: yeah You are right @Hitesh Jain Actually when i'm populating value then it stretch, i was wrong that time

Comment: I'm using this layout with tabwidget in this case it stretch...so please tell me how to do this

Answer (score 1):

You need to alter your xml as below:

```
//alter both LinearLayout as
android:layout_weight="25"
android:layout_height="0dp"

//alter ListView as
android:layout_weight="50"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:isScrollContainer="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your `list view` inside a `linear layout` and give `layout_weight="50"` to the       `linear layout`.Then make the `listview` width and height to `fill parent`.

Also give linear_layout `layout height="0dp"`

Comment: i used this but no effect if i don't use android:id then working but when i use id then this problem occur

Comment: have you tested it on emulator or real device??