# LinearLayout Weights not working inside Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-linearlayout

I have searched and found that many people have reported this issue.
These are some of the links that I have gone throught :

- [How to use android:layout_weight with listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893396/how-to-use-androidlayout-weight-with-listview)
- [Android, ListView layout_weight not working, height set to 0dp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21313240/android-listview-layout-weight-not-working-height-set-to-0dp)
- [Android - Linear layout weight not working properly in listview items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28076091/android-linear-layout-weight-not-working-properly-in-listview-items)
- [why is my layout_weight not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36023338/why-is-my-layout-weight-not-working)
- [Android - layout_weight not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20060964/android-layout-weight-not-working)
- [Android Inside Custom ListView, TextView Weight property not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997314/android-inside-custom-listview-textview-weight-property-not-working)
- [Android Layout_Weight for Fixed Width Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22725258/android-layout-weight-for-fixed-width-not-working)

and some others as well

These links have suggested the following solutions

1. Replacing  mInflater.inflate(resID, parent, false); with mInflater.inflate(resID, null, false);
2. Making list view as 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   I even tried experimenting with fill_parent but it didnt work.
3. Listview inside another linear layout
4. Row xml inside a Relative layout and withing that a Linear layout
5. For Horizontal orientation make android:layout_width="0dp". When I do this, the listview is not poplutated. It remains blank

I am not able find anything for this particular problem in android documentation either.

My list view:

```
  android:id="@+id/lst_stocks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/row_heading"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_5"
```

My other xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/border"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="3">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:text="Rating"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxEms="10"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Companay"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_sector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxEms="10"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Sector"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I am using this xml file in other places as well, where it works perfectly fine.

- So what am I missing. Why are the Linear layout weights not working?
- Guidelines for using LinearLayouts inside Listviews effectively

P.S. I have run the files on two separate mobiles and not on a emulator.

Comment: You need your width set to 0 for those items using weight **not** on your `ListView`

Comment: Couple other quick notes. You don't need `orientation` in ` horizontal layout as it is the default. Also, it's better to not set the `weightSum` unless you have a reason to and let the device do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make TextView layout_width as 0dp.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3">


    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_rating"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:text="Rating"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxEms="10"
     android:padding="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Companay"
    android:textAlignment="center"
     android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    />

  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/txt_sector"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_weight="1"
  android:ellipsize="end"
  android:maxEms="10"
  android:padding="@dimen/margin_10"
  android:singleLine="true"
  android:text="Sector"
  android:textAlignment="center"
  android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use weight to set your height of `TextView`, then you should do this :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_sector"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"   // Change is done here
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:maxEms="10"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_10"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Sector"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />`
```

Similarly if you are looking to set width, you can use `width="0dp"` and `wieght="1"`.